# OCaml - can't find Sys.big_endian value in Core

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I just realized that `val big_endian : bool` is removed from the `Sys` module when opening `Core.Std`.

Where can I find a similar value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to vanilla OCaml `Sys` module using `Caml` module that includes the standard library:

```
 let big_endian = Caml.Sys.big_endian
```

Anyway, it is really interesting, why they do not provided anything similar.